# Compatibility Between MS-Access 2003 and MS-Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, backwards-compatibility

This is similar to a question that I've asked yesterday, but I've managed to find a fair bit more information: enough to warrant a new question, I feel.

My office has recently moved to Windows 7 along with Office 2013 - with the except of Access which has stayed as 2003.

Access works absolutely fine except when I try to automate Excel. This is a feature of nearly all my applications.

When I load an old project, the reference is automatically updated to "Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library" - it is held as an EXE file in Program Files (x86). Note: it does not say the reference is missing.

When I try to run any code which uses early binding, it fails with the following error message: "Error in loading DLL"

I've since tried late binding by doing the following:

```
Dim app As Object
Dim wb As Object
Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
app.Visible = True
Set wb = app.Workbooks.Add
```

This creates the Application, it becomes visible, a Workbook is added, but then I get the following error: "Run-time error '1004':

Application-definted or object-defined error"

If I try to access VBA in the new Workbook I get the following error: "An error occurred initializing the VBA libraries (1004)" The Workbook is loaded in "Compatibility Mode"

The above leads me to believe that the 2 applications may not be compatable, but the following is worth considering:

If I try to use early binding I don't get the Intellisense drop-downs but words like Workbook and Worksheet do auto-capitalise themselves as you would normally expect them to. The code won't compile at all if I don't have the reference set, but it does compile - and throw and error - when it is. I've since tried Word 2013 - who's Object Reference is an OLB file rather than EXE - and I get the full Intellisense features I would except, but it still throws the same error when trying to run.

In a nut shell, does anyone know if I stand any chance of having the 2 work together?

Thanks